# bind click event to anchor tag in for each loop in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying a bind a click event to dynamically created attribute.

```
$.each(data, function(index, names){
    $("#names").append("<tr><td>"+id+"</td><td><a href='marks.jsp' id='Test' style='color:red;font-size:11px;'>"+subect +"</td></tr>");
});
```

on display page hyperlink will be added to subject and when clicked it has to open to marks.jsp.

Thanks

Comment: You're missing an open-quote before the `</td>`.

Comment: Yes u are missing the " over here +subect +</td></tr>" before the </td>

Answer (score 0):

Make syntax corrections based on above comments and then try:

```
$("a#Test").on('click',function(){
//perform action here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#names').on('click','a',function(){
//perform action here
});
```

[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/)

Answer (score 0):

Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for binding events on dynamically created elements

```
$.each(data, function(index, names){
    $("#names").append("<tr><td>"+id+"</td><td><a id='link1' href='marks.jsp' id='Test'
               style='color:red;font-size:11px;'>"+subect +"</td></tr>");
});

$('#names').on('click','#link1',function(){
  // do whatever you want on clicking the link
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you are wrong id always meant tobe unique if you want to bind same click event to every link then try this

```
$.each(data, function(index, names){
    $("#names").append("<tr><td>"+id+"</td><td><a href='marks.jsp' name='Test' style='color:red;font-size:11px;'>"+subect +"</td></tr>");
});



$("[name=Test]").click(function(){
     //Do your stuff.
});
```